# Offline geocoding and reverse geocoding for Android

Tags: openstreetmap, geocoding, android, reverse-geocoding, offline

I'm developing an Android application that cannot use internet and need to deal with maps and positioning.

Download OpenStreetMap data seems to be a good solution to access map information offline. However, I need some basic algorithms running locally on the cellphone, like geocoding and reverse geocoding.

Does anybody know a library for Android that can consume offline OpenStreetMap data and provide geocoding and reverse geocoding on the cellphone?

Comment: I think you will need to define your users 'Offline' area or file sizes will be too large for fast offline geocoding see: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18565/is-there-a-method-to-create-offline-geocoder-using-osm-xml-data

Comment: Here (Nokia) have it in their HERE API - have tested this in the HERE beta apk (sideloaded) http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/nokia-x/here-maps/user-guide/places/geocoding-and-reverse-geocoding.html apk http://here.com/beta/android/?lang=en-US

Comment: Check out skobbler's OSM SDK - they offer offline geocoding http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/android#sec019

Comment: Plz stop crossposting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27175346/offline-geocoding-and-reverse-geocoding-for-android

Answer (score 1):

[ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Android](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/) supports offline geocoding, reverse geocoding, and routing.  The API is the same for online & offline, you only need to initialize the task, e.g. `RouteTask`, for local route or online route.  The [Locator](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/core/tasks/geocode/Locator.html) abstract class is used for creating offline/online geocoders.

Here is a SDK sample [source code](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-runtime-samples-android/tree/master/OfflineRoutingAndGeocoding) to investigate

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is (currently) no such lib https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Frameworks

Comment: But lots of [end-user applications](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Android), maybe one of them provides the geocoding task as a lib?